# What is the number of graphs with unlabeled (non isolated) nodes and 3 labeled edges?

Tags: graph-theory

The OEIS sequence A014500 is the number of graphs with unlabeled (non isolated) nodes and n labeled edges.  I am trying to count the case for n=3.  I have 1 graph (a triangle)  with 3 nodes.  3 length 3 path graphs, 3 graphs containing a path of length 2 and a path of length 1, and 1 graph containing 3 paths of length 1.  The OEIS sequence says there should be 9

Comment: I think you've missed a star graph: one vertex of degree $3$ and three of degree $1$.

Comment: @ saulpatz  Yes you are correct, Thanks.